# How can I persist a variable across Activities?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a File object called currentFile. When currentFile has been changed and the user attempts to open a new file without saving first a Save dialog is presented and if Yes is clicked currentFile is saved. The problem I'm having is that when I start a new Activity and press the Android back button, currentFile is set to null so changing the file, attempting to open a new one results in a NullPointerException. How can I persist currentFile across Activities?

Comment: Can you post some code, posts like these tend to get down voted.

Comment: Also you might want to use a static variable.

Comment: Yes I will I'm just not sure what I should paste. Gimme a sec

Comment: @RapsFan1981 post the code to both your classes so we can see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, that you **don't** want to pass the file to the other Activity but you want to retain its value in your first Activity because it becomes `null` if your Activity is paused/stopped and resumed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's several ways to do this, depending on what you want to do you should put on a balance what's better for your needs, one way is using extras to pass the variable value to another activity

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString(key, value);
Intent intent = new Intent("your.activity");
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

Another approach is to set a variable in your application context, creating a class that extends from Application and which reference you will be able to get from any activity using

```
YorApplicationClass app = (YorApplicationClass)getApplication();
app.getYourVariable();
```

And the last i can think of is using SharedPreferences, storing variables as key/value pairs that can be used for any activity...

```
            SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            Editor edit = pref.edit();
            edit.putString(key, value);
            edit.commit();

            //Any activity
            SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            pref.getString(key, defValue);
```

Regards!

Comment: Thanks! extending the Application class is new to me so learning this was another step forward for me.

Comment: Great, dont forget to declare it in the manifest application tag in order to get it reference properly... Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `Intents` & `Extras`.

```
String yourFileName = "path/to/your/file"; 
Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity, newActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("FileName", yourFileName);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your new activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String file = extras.getString("FileName");
}
```

Here is some reading on `Intents`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: I do use this for the application's back button but I'm having the problem with the Android back button, if the user uses the Android's back button rather than my button.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this using the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class.  I find it easier to work with than using bundles and intents.

To access your application class, just call getApplicationContext in any activity, and cast it to your class type which extends Application like so:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        MyApplicationClass app = (MyApplicationClass)this.getApplication();
    }
}
```